# What does overloading true and false operators do?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am only a beginner to C#, but am trying to learn everything. However, I am stuck on the overloading true and false; what does this mean? Please (try to) give replies as basic as possible (so that even a '13' yr old understands the logic).
(Please make to sure make it as understandable as possible, thank you).
If you can, please explain what the outcome would be if the coord had changed to something else (such as: (3,5)).

I have pre-made code right here:
(Can you lease explain the different outputs on changing the coordinates)
Info:
- Program is a console application
- C#
I have made a class called Coord (standing for co-ordinates).
Inside Class:

```
class Coord
{
    private int _x, _y;

    public Coord(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x; 
        _y = y;
    }

    public int x
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _x; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _x = value; 
        }
    }

    public int y
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _y; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _y = value; 
        }
    }

    public static bool operator true(Coord coord1)
    {
        if (coord1.x != 0 || coord1.y != 0)
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        else
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    }

    public static bool operator false(Coord coord1)
    {
        if (coord1.x == 0 && coord1.y == 0)
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        else
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Inside Main class Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Coord coord = new Coord(0, 0);

        if (coord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Debugging your own code by stepping through each line would help you understand what your program is doing.

Comment: After you have tried debugging your code, if you still have a question, please ensure that you have provided a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: My bad, why didn't i just do that!

Comment: Can you please tell me why the false operator block is not being accessed (skipped) when debugging?

Comment: It was a C# version 1 design mistake, inspired because it did not yet have nullable types.  What's done cannot be undone but you can certainly stop using it.  A property with a name like IsEmpty would be a sane choice.  Or just using [a .NET type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of writing your own.  Or making it nullable.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not following your train of thought here; how does operator true / false relate to a lack of nullable types?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx

Comment: This is just code from a website tutorial on overloading true and false operators.

Comment: @HansPassant: Interesting. I never reviewed that documentation. Had I done so I would have made a thorough critique of the use of operator true and false for the proposed DBNull type.

Comment: Hehe, yes, it was carefully crafted to stop C# programmers from using it.

Comment: In particular: we expect that `if(X() && Y()) Z();` and `if(X()) if (Y()) Z();` have the same semantics, but for the given type, they do not! The former evaluates `Y()` when `X()` is "null", but the latter does not. (Though fortunately neither executes `Z()`, which is something at least.)

Comment: @Johnny: I note also that your example here is a poor use of `operator true` and `operator false` because the type does not overload the `&` and `|` operators! The *right* way to to this is, as Hans says, an `IsZero` helper method. The idiom, common in C, of `if(blah)` for a blah that is not Boolean is considered by many, myself included, to be bad style in C#. If you do want to do this thing, the right way to do it for your coordinate type is a user-defined implicit conversion to bool, not `operator true`.  Only implement op true if you mean to implement `&&` and `||` with lazy semantics.

Answer (score 5):

> I am only a beginner to C#, but am trying to learn everything.

Make sure to allocate a couple of decades minimum. I learn new things about this language quite frequently.

> I am stuck on the overloading true and false; what does this mean?

They are seldom used; they are primarily needed to make user-defined `&&` and `||` operators be short-circuiting.

Read my series of articles on this subject; you will be particularly interested in part three but you should read the whole thing.

https://ericlippert.com/2012/03/26/null-is-not-false-part-one/

> If you can, please explain what the outcome would be if the coord had changed to something else (such as: (3,5)).

If you want to know what a program does when you change something, *change it and run it* and soon you will know!

Comment: ... well, you are 'very' helpful